# How to install CentOS on VirtualBox?

Tags: centos

It seems CentOS is divided into CentOS Linux and CentOS Stream. CentOS Linux is dated 2009 now that it is 2022, so it seems it is out of date. CentOS Stream has version 8 and 9.

But version 8 and 9 have:

> Cloud | Containers | Vagrant

It doesn't seem like it is for VirtualBox while Ubuntu and Mint / Arch Linux still worked the same way.  How do we install CentOS using VirtualBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the download site [here](https://www.centos.org/centos-stream/) you'll see that `Cloud | Containers | Vagrant` are listed under `Others`:

[image: CentOS Download Options]

If you want to just download the CentOS Stream for the version you want, click the purple "x86_64" link. This will download the full **DVD** version, which is quite large, but includes all the packages you will need to install CentOS GUIs, etc.

If you want a smaller boot ISO, for example installing a minimal server, follow the link on the page for downloading [via Torrent](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/8-stream/isos/x86_64/) (the link says torrent, but most seem to be plain http/https downloads).

[Here](https://linuxhint.com/install_centos8_netboot_iso/) is a step by step guide on using the boot ISO if you need help with that.

Comment: for example, the one with a windows GUI is 8GB?  What about the one that is about 800MB? It doesn't have a windows GUI?

Comment: @pokemon The 8GB includes a GUI and a bunch of other things. If you want, you can install use the 800MB iso. It requires internet connectivity to install additional packages; for example you can check the 'Server with a GUI' box under `Software Selection`. See here: https://linuxhint.com/install_centos8_netboot_iso/

Comment: uh that's right... I tried the 800MB one and the installation downloaded about an additional 1.3GB and had GUI... just hope it is written as to what they are